WebApi docs for Note Station
Do you guys know if there is any Note Station API documentation?
I read https://kb.synology.com/pl-pl/DG/DSM_Login_Web_API_Guide/1 and I prepared some request to my NAS (DSM 7.2). Getting API info works well, I can see some entries about Note Station in given response:
....
"SYNO.NoteStation.Export.Note": {
"maxVersion": 1,
"minVersion": 1,
"path": "entry.cgi",
"requestFormat": "JSON"
},
"SYNO.NoteStation.Export.Notebook": {
"maxVersion": 1,
"minVersion": 1,
"path": "entry.cgi",
"requestFormat": "JSON"
},
....

but what next? Should I guess what methods and parameters are supported by for example SYNO.NoteStation.Export.Notebook API?
I found some documentation for File Station API
https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf
is there anything similar for Note Station?
